# remove keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I first started using Ubuntu, only a German keyboard layout was setup in

System | Preferences | Keyboard

As the keyboard is actually a UK keyboard, I added a UK keyboard and removed the German keyboard. However, every time I log out, then back in again, the German keyboard is restored as the default (the UK keyboard is also available).

Is there a way that I can permanently remove the German keyboard, such that the UK keyboard is always used by default?

Comment: What is you default locale?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

*Settings → Region & Language → Input sources*

Select and remove "German".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the login manager that still has the German keyboard layout.

To try and fix this, select the appropriate keyboard layout on the next login.

Comment: I can't see anything in the login screen that allows me to configure the keyboard layout

Comment: Are using lightdm or gdm as our login manager?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `System Settings` in Dash or through `Super+A` and run it .Select the keyboard layout option as under the menu and Remove the `German` keyboard layout entry from here and try logout and login back. There is also a Keyboard layout option in Log-In screen , try to change it there too if this does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to remove keyboard layouts but the following will resolve the problem.

To change the keyboard to uk / gb layout use the following command in a terminal

```
setxkbmap gb
```

This setting will be permanent and remain after logging out or re-booting.